# Showing that $f((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)):=x_1-y_1$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, continuity, solution-verification

Define $f:\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)):=x_1-y_1
$$
I want to show that $f$ is continuous. I already know that the function $g(x,y):=x-y$ is continuous, so define $h:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
$$
h((x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)):=g(x_1,x_2)+g(x_2,y_1)+ g(y_2,y_2)=x_1-y_1
$$
Since $h$ is composed of a sum of continuous functions, it is itself continuous. Because $f((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=h((x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4))$ we can conclude that also $f$ is continuous.

Is there something wrong with my argumentation or is this enough to prove that $f$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct but your argumentation is a mess (there is no product going on here). First prove that the projection $\pi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\pi(x, y) = x$ is continuous. Then, since $f = \pi \circ g$, it follows that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Sorry, I had made a mistake when I wrote it. I meant to write $h$ as a sum of functions.

Comment: You define $\pi :\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, but the codomain of $g$ is $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: do you mean $g\circ \pi$?, and I agree with Logi we would need a modification of $\pi$ to match domains, but the argument works: $g(\pi(x_1,x_2),\pi(y_1,y_2))=g(x_1,y_1)=x_1-y_1$.

Comment: @AndrewSotomayor, but is my argument wrong? I mean a sum of continuous functions is also continuous, so why does $h$ not show that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @Logi Ah, I thought you defined $g$ as the subtraction of vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but I see now it was just the subtraction of two real numbers. But you just need to prove the subtraction of two vectors is continuous then, which is pretty easy

Comment: @AndrewSotomayor I did mean $\pi \circ g$, because I thought $g$ subtracted two vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, not the subtraction of two real numbers. But my idea still works